# View the saved passwords in PgAdmin4 for MAC OS

Tags: pgadmin-4

I know the master password of the pgAdmin4. I am able to login to pgAdmin and then login to the database as well using the saved server password.

But I did not find any option to view the saved password in pgAdmin GUI.

How can I view it?

Answer (score -1):

The pgAdmin4 uses a sqlite file: ~.pgadmin4.db. you can connect to it using Intellij, or any other suitable db query tool, and query the server table which contains all the server connections:

```
select * from server;
```

All the passwords are encrypted. If needed can be decrypted with the master password.

Comment: This answer is missing how it should be decrypted, there is a similar StackOverflow answer with the details that it should be AES CFB8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76310467/1390830

Comment: @jackofallcode did it ask about decrypting the password?

Comment: Technically the question did not ask about decrypting it no. But its really useful information, so I was trying to help others that found this answer.